# What is the Big-O and exact runtime

Tags: python, runtime, big-o

```
def alg 3(n)
  x = 0
  i = 1
  while i < n:
     for j in range(0, n**3,n*3): 
        x += 1
     i *= 3 
  return x
```

I don't really get the Big-O and exact runtime of this code. I first thought that the Big-O is O(n^3) * logn because of the n**3 but the n * 3 confuses me. Could someone please explain that problem? Thanks.

Comment: What should this algorithm do?

Comment: The for loop looks like `O(n**2)`. Instead of taking 1 step at a time to reach `n**3`, it's taking `3n` steps. so `total steps = (n**3/3n) => O(n**2)`

Comment: You have approx. n/3 `while` loops. In each, you have approx. n^3 / 3n = n^2 / 3 loops. So, you have O(n * n^2) = O(n^3). The constants don't matter.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille--why is while loop n/3 rather than log(n) (i.e. since i will be 1, 3, 9, 27, ... log n, thus, exponential values up to log n to base 3)?  Seems the answer should be O(n^2)*log(n) since as you mention constants don't matter.

Comment: @DarrylG I don't think that's quite right. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/etqse220yv

Comment: @droptop--I don't quite follow why the plot of n/3 and log(n) mean it's "not quite right".  Can you explain it further?  My statement that constants don't matter relates to the O notation (i.e. where constants don't matter for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute the complexity we have to decompose the problem into two sub problems:

1. the inner for: the complexity of this one is n³/3n ~ O(n²)
2. the outer while: how many steps i needs to reach n:

   1. first step i = 1
   2. second step i = 3
   3. third step i = 3*3 = 9
   4. kth step i = 3^k

hence the solution for the second sub-problem is log3(k) ~ O(log(k))

the final complexity is: first sub-problem complexity multiplied by the second sub-problem complexity --> O(n²log(n))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I got it.